# Javascript How to get image name on click

Tags: javascript

I have a website and there's a gallery . what i just want is when user click on a image in the gallery it must come a popup box and get the image name as a value .

for an example i want to buy a item, and send order notice to admin by go to site -> gallery and click the item i would like to buy , when i click the item ( AKA Image ) it must come a popup box and fill some information there like name, email, phone number and etc, amd it must automatically get the name of image and when user submit the form admin must get an email with the image name and the form filled details .

is it possible to do with javascript ?

Comment: Yes. So what's your specific question?

Comment: can you please give a snippet or something similar to my procedure ? so i can modify it to my requirements . what i just need when click on an image get the image name , and user must fill the rest of the fields after that when submit the form i must get an email . please help me sir 

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a help site. Questions here must be *specific*. Try doing it yourself, if you get stuck we can help you.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#imageId").click(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    var nameAr = src.split('/');
    alert(nameAr[nameAr.length-1]);

});
```

you can use it..